# Creating a dll library in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015

It would appear that the example couldn't get any simpler:

```
//Example.h  
#pragma once

#ifdef EXPORTING_DLL
extern __declspec(dllexport) void HelloWorld();
#else
extern __declspec(dllimport) void HelloWorld();
#endif    



//Example.cpp  
#include "Functions.h"

#define EXPORTING_DLL

void HelloWorld()
{

}
```

So, what I have problems with? OK, when trying to compile as it is, that is after creation of dll type project in VS, I'm getting warning:
***warning C4273: 'HelloWorld': inconsistent dll linkage***
if I change definition of HelloWorld in cpp file to:

```
   __declspec(dllimport) void HelloWorld()
    {
    }
```

I'm getting error:

***Error    C2491   'HelloWorld': definition of dllimport function not allowed***
If on the other hand I change definition of HelloWorld to:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void HelloWorld()
{

}
```

I'm getting warning:

**Warning   C4273   'HelloWorld': inconsistent dll linkage**
Any idea how to define it so it compiles without any warnings? I mean, those warnings are at least worrying.

Comment: You define `EXPORTING_DLL` after you include the header file. Therefore when the headerfile is included it thinks its importing the dll.

Comment: @MikeVine Hi Mike, hey, I think you should add this comment as an answer so I can accept it. For now +1 and huge thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `EXPORTING_DLL` *before* you include the header. That way the header can declare the correct prototype based on whether you are importing or exporting.

Without doing this it will import which is not what you want